# How to get sorted by distinct or group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have a table 'items' (more than 1,000,000 rows), 12 columns:

```
id | name | group_id | cost   | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 | column11 | column12
1  | A1   | 100      | 10,00  | c_15    | c_16    | c_17    | c_18    | c_19    | c_110    | c_111    | c_112
2  | A2   | 300      | 17,00  | c_25    | c_26    | c_27    | c_28    | c_29    | c_210    | c_211    | c_212
3  | A3   | 200      | 16,24  | c_35    | c_36    | c_37    | c_38    | c_39    | c_310    | c_311    | c_312
4  | A4   | 100      |  8,01  | c_45    | c_46    | c_47    | c_48    | c_49    | c_410    | c_411    | c_412
5  | A5   | 100      | 19,62  | c_55    | c_56    | c_57    | c_58    | c_59    | c_510    | c_511    | c_512
6  | A6   | 400      | 10,00  | c_65    | c_66    | c_67    | c_68    | c_69    | c_610    | c_611    | c_612
7  | A7   | 200      | 16,22  | c_75    | c_76    | c_77    | c_78    | c_79    | c_710    | c_711    | c_712
8  | A8   | 300      |  7,00  | c_85    | c_86    | c_87    | c_88    | c_89    | c_810    | c_811    | c_812
```

How can I get rows with unique group_id and lowest cost for that group_id and sort for any column (name, column5, column6 etc)?

Eg sorted for column5:

```
id | name | group_id | cost   | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 | column11 | column12
4  | A4   | 100      |  8,01  | c_45    | c_46    | c_47    | c_48    | c_49    | c_410    | c_411    | c_412
6  | A6   | 400      | 10,00  | c_65    | c_66    | c_67    | c_68    | c_69    | c_610    | c_611    | c_612
7  | A7   | 200      | 16,22  | c_75    | c_76    | c_77    | c_78    | c_79    | c_710    | c_711    | c_712
8  | A8   | 300      |  7,00  | c_85    | c_86    | c_87    | c_88    | c_89    | c_810    | c_811    | c_812
```

Eg sorted for cost:

```
id | name | group_id | cost   | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 | column11 | column12
8  | A8   | 300      |  7,00  | c_85    | c_86    | c_87    | c_88    | c_89    | c_810    | c_811    | c_812
4  | A4   | 100      |  8,01  | c_45    | c_46    | c_47    | c_48    | c_49    | c_410    | c_411    | c_412
6  | A6   | 400      | 10,00  | c_65    | c_66    | c_67    | c_68    | c_69    | c_610    | c_611    | c_612
7  | A7   | 200      | 16,22  | c_75    | c_76    | c_77    | c_78    | c_79    | c_710    | c_711    | c_712
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL have a special syntax for this - [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html):

```
with cte as (
    select distinct on (group_id)
        *
    from Table1
    order by group_id, cost
)
select *
from cte
order by column5
```

I don't recommend to use `*` in production, here I'm using it only to simplify code.

Comment: how many records do you have as a result? do you have index on `group_id, cost` columns?

Comment: Yes, I have. And I got 900k records (around 90% of all).

Comment: It needs 5 secs, if I change your query to "with cte as (
    select distinct on (group_id)
        id, column5
    from Table1
    order by group_id, cost
)
select id
from cte
order by column5"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) function:

```
select * from
(
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER
     (PARTITION BY group_id  order by cost) as rn
from items
) as i  
where i.rn=1
order by column5
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28271/1)</kbd>

Comment: 59 second to query... to slow mate

Comment: @brigantaggior: "too slow" won't get you any further help with tuning that query. Please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions to understand which information is necessary if a query is "too slow". I'd guess that putting an index on `group_id, cost` might help for that query.

Comment: I have 4 indexes, and on these columns too. Whats more information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
with cte as (
    select distinct on (group_id) id, column5
    from prices
    order by group_id, cost
)
select id
from cte
order by column5
```

Works perfectly with 1-2 columns